# Is there any way linking GPO with ou using the ou canonical name?

Tags: windows, powershell, gpo

Is there a way i can link GPO with an OU by its canonical name?

```
New-Gplink -gpo <gponame> -target <CANONICAL NAME>
```

From what I've read we can use only the distinguished name. maybe there's a way around it?
Im using this to save all of them in a variable

```
$test=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName | Select-Object -Property CanonicalName
```

now using a gui i open a window for the user to select an ou from there

```
foreach ($item in $test){ 
[void]$listbox.items.add($item)}
```

So now i can catch the user choise by using:

```
$catch = $listbox.selected.item
```

so if i now would like to link the gpo using

```
new-gplink -gpo <gponame> -target $catch
```

I will get an error.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
# Get the OU objects, which include the DN, plus the CN
$test = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName

# Add the values to your listbox - there's an AddRange method for arrays
[void]$listbox.Items.AddRange($test.CanonicalName)

# Find the object that matches the currently selected Canonical Name
$CatchDN = $test | Where-Object { $_.CanonicalName -eq ($listbox.SelectedItem) }

# Because $CatchDN is an object, just link the GPO using the object.
New-GpLink -Name <gponame> -Target $CatchDN
```

No tested the above using forms, but it should work as intended.

Comment: First line- if this without piping to select-object then the listbox would not have canonical names but would have distinguishedname and the rest of the code wont do it .. thanks thoug

Comment: Get-AdOrgansationalUnit returns DN by default, if you specify CanonicalName property parameter it's returned in additon to the default properties. If you post your full code then maybe we can put you right - the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using your own form code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'GPO Connector V1.0'
$form.Size = '600,200'
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1.Location = '10,120'
$button1.Size = '75,23'
$button1.Text = 'Link'
$button1.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom'
$button1.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $button1

$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Location = '90,120'
$button2.Size = '75,23'
$button2.Text = 'UnLink'
$button2.Anchor = 'Left,Bottom'
$Button2.Add_Click($Button2_Click)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = '80,20'
$label.Size = '480,20'
$label.Text = 'SELECT GPO And Corresponding OU (ONLY WORKSTATION OU)'

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($label,$button1,$button2))

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Location = '10,40'
$listBox.Size = '260,80'
$listbox.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom'

$listBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox2.Location = '300,40'
$listBox2.Size = '260,80'
$listbox2.Anchor = 'Top,Left,Bottom,Right'

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($listBox,$listBox2))

$button1.Add_Click({
    # Find the object that matches the currently selected Canonical Name
    $CatchDN = $Script:OUlist | Where-Object { $_.CanonicalName -eq ($listbox2.SelectedItem) }
    Write-Host "Selected CN object: $CatchDN"
    # Because $CatchDN is an object, just link the GPO using the object.
    $LinkedGP = $Script:GPOlist | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq ($listBox.SelectedItem) }
    Write-Host "Selected GPO: "$LinkedGP.DisplayName
    $LinkedGP | New-GpLink -Target $CatchDN -WhatIf
})

# Show form first, then load data to lists
$form.Add_Shown({
    # Retrieve GPO list
    $Script:OUlist = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName
    # Add OU CN to listbox
    $listbox2.Items.AddRange($Script:OUlist.CanonicalName)
    $Script:GPOlist = Get-GPO -All # list of GPO
    $listbox.Items.AddRange($Script:GPOlist.DisplayName)
})

$form.Topmost = $true
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
$form.Dispose()
```